# Object hierarchy and types in javascript: why Number and String are functions and not objects?

Tags: javascript, class-hierarchy

Just asking why

```
typeof Number
```

provides *function* as a result.

Other built-in objects like *Math* or *JSON* are objects and, according to this answer ( [What does the built in object hierarchy look like in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891453/what-does-the-built-in-object-hierarchy-look-like-in-javascript) ), they should all be related to *Object*, not to *Function*.

Javascript design flaw or there's a meaning in that?
Is that answer correct?

Comment: Functions are Objects too :)

Comment: Of course, but the real question is why *String* Inherits from *Function* and *JSON* Inherits from *Object*. I can see no sense in this. 
For example if you add a method to the Function prototype, it will be available to String but not to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. In JavaScript
>   every function is actually a Function object.

Functions are glorified objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

> Of course, but the real question is why String Inherits from Function
>   and JSON Inherits from Object. I can see no sense in this. For example
>   if you add a method to the Function prototype, it will be available to
>   String but not to JSON

A JavaScript object is a mapping between keys and values. Keys are strings and values can be anything. This makes objects a natural fit for hashmaps.

Functions are regular objects with the additional capability of being callable.

You can instantiate a String but you cannot instantiate a Math object. This is maybe the fact confusing you.

```js
alert(new String());
alert(new Math());
```

Comment: That's clear, but why *Function*, *JSON* or *Math* built-ins are derived from *Object* but *String* and *Number* are instead derived form *Function* (which in turns Inherits from *Object*)? This is what i don't understand. But maybe there is no answer to this question :)

Comment: Check the second part of my answer. :)

Comment: @gerryino Added something for you.

Comment: @gerryino: Notice that `Function` is indeed derived from `Function`. Only `JSON` and `Math` are no functions.